# How do i create an incrementing array of objects, User1, User2 etc. with object values attached to each entry?

Tags: javascript, increment

Trying to get an array of temporary users, where next user should be "user" + ArrayOfUsers.length, but i have no idea of how to get there, even after 2 hours of googleing.

Each user in the array should be attached with object values of my standard user defined like this.

```
function user(name, email, code){
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.code = code;
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: _"where next user should be "user" + ArrayOfUsers.length"_: isn't really clear. Are you wanting the code or the name to be `user1` `user2` etc for each new user?

Comment: I need to create users at the push of a button, prompting for name, email and password using the variable user + arrayOfUser.length. Then i push the new user into the array, and thereby increment the length of the array. At a later point in the process i need to make a table showing the names and emails, but i got that part covered.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't support declaring variables with dynamic names...But you can assign a dynamic key to a window object (or any other object), and access them as variable names (Only applicable for keys set to window object).

Please note that this won't work in strict mode `use strict`.

And I'm not sure why you want it as a dynamic variable. Anyways you could do it like below.

You could keep a count variable and set variable to window object using

`this["user"+index] = newUser;`

Try the below snippet...

```js
function user(name, email, code) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.code = code;
}



var index = 0;
function createUser(name, email,code){
    const newUser = new user(name, email, code);
    this["user"+index] = newUser;
    index++;
    return newUser;
}

createUser("a", "a@a.com", 1);
createUser("b", "b@b.com", 2)

for(let i = 0; i< index; i++){
  console.log(this["user"+ i]);
}

console.log(user0);
console.log(user1);
```

Comment: This puts the incementing number into the name part of the variable, i need it to be incrementing the variable instead. Can you help with that as well?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please upvote/mark as right answer if found helpful . Good day :)